# Offline Plotly templating - it's possible?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using Python Plotly chart library in order to build graphs from my Python-Django web-application and inject them to templates as shown below:

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter

def index(request):
    x_data = [0,1,2,3]
    y_data = [x**2 for x in x_data]
    plot_div = plot([Scatter(x=x_data, y=y_data,
                        mode='lines', name='test',
                        opacity=0.8, marker_color='green')],
               output_type='div')
    return render(request, "index.html", context={'plot_div': plot_div})
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% autoescape off %}
  {{ plot_div }}
  {% endautoescape %}
</body>
</html>
```

Those bunch of lines of code generate a simple scatter graph and will show it to the client template, now I want to use a different theme template, as reported in the docs ([HERE](https://plot.ly/python/templates/)), Plotly has a lot of default templates ready-to-use, but I can't figure out how to use them in my offline chart view renderer. how I can use the `plotly_white` template in my graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after trying in many ways, i've found a solution.

Basically, we need to:

- Build the axes objects
- Create a layout with the `template` object that defines the axis dictionary and the template to use
- Create the figure object that contains the graph with the axes and the custom Layout
- Plot the chart to a div container

Here a snippet of the code that i've used:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot



def plot1d():
    x_data = np.arange(0, 120, 0.1)
    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x=x_data,
        y=np.sin(x_data),
    )
    trace2 = go.Scatter(
        x=x_data,
        y=np.cos(x_data),
    )

    data = [trace1, trace2]
    layout = go.Layout(
        # autosize=False,
        # width=900,
        # height=500,
        template='plotly_dark',
        xaxis=dict(
            autorange=True
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            autorange=True
        )
    )
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    plot_div = plot(fig, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs=False)
    return plot_div
```

And here the final result:

[image: Chart Result]